# Why $y^2\ge x^4$ can be written as $|y|\ge x^2$?

Tags: calculus, absolute-value

I'm studying the domain of $f(x,y)=\sqrt{y^2-x^4}$

Comment: Because the square root is monotone on the positive half axis and $\vert y\vert^2=y^2$.

Comment: Some authors define the absolute value of a real number as the (positive) square root of its square.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As $y^2 \geq 0$ and $x^{4} \geq 0$, we may write
$$\sqrt{y^2} \geq \sqrt{x^4},$$
which indicates that
$$\lvert y\rvert \geq x^{2}$$

Answer (score 1):

Note that
$$
y^2\geq x^4 \iff 0\leq y^2 - x^4=(|y|-x^2)(|y|+x^2)\iff|y|\geq x^2.
$$